# Sticky Navigation Blocks Full Page Stack Snippets

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, top-bar

If you're using the sticky navigation option that pins the navigation to the top of the screen and try to run a stack snippet in full screen mode, it cuts off the rendered code:

[image]

Since the navigation bar is 60px tall, full page stack snippets could have at least 60px added to the top margin of the body when the sticky navigation option is enabled to push the code down enough that it isn't cut off.

Comment: I'm thinking the result is that a dev increased the `z-index` value of the top bar recently to `1049`. This has caused several problems, including other aspects of the site being covered: [default/tooltip w/ `z-index:1049`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17NJc.jpg) vs [tooltip w/ `z-index:1050`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym2RG.jpg).